# Why provide a Linux distro as a Dockerfile base when my host has all the software I need installed?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to start writing a Docker image. I have a .net Core 2.0 Web Api service that I have deployed to an Amazon Linux machine. It runs fine, but I would like to automate the build and deployment process a bit.

As far as I am concerned, there is no need for a Parent image for the image I need to build. I might grab some files from a location, run some dotnet CLI commands, and run the service using Apache as a reverse proxy. I dont really see the need for a parent image in any of that.

I am asking this question because most of the examples I have seen include a base image. Most of the time its something very generic, like "From Ubuntu". I have read that most images will include a parent image. According to Docker's documentation:

> A parent image is the image that your image is based on. It refers to the contents of the FROM directive in the Dockerfile. Each subsequent declaration in the Dockerfile modifies this parent image. Most Dockerfiles start from a parent image, rather than a base image. However, the terms are sometimes used interchangeably.

What exactly is the point of inheriting from Ubuntu? Even the Docker docs suggest using Debian "since it’s very tightly controlled and kept minimal". Does that just ensure that your Linux machine has an Ubuntu distribution? Does it even matter if I am using Amazon Linux but use the Debian image as my base?

Comment: Where do you expect to get *any software at all* if you aren't coming from a distro? Let's say you're running Apache HTTPD. You need to actually have a libc for it to link to, a copy of OpenSSL. Heck, you can't `apt-get install apache` if you don't have `apt-get` (or `yum` or another package manager), and all that's provided by your distro.

Comment: ...the closest you can get to not-having-a-distro is something like [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/), and even that is still a distro (just one which, at compile time, builds everything to exactly your specs with no binary packages involved).

Comment: (Well -- there's [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/), but if you want to know what the point of using a real distro instead... try using it. Fine learning experience, but not something that helps you get actual work done).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I just had a moment of clarity. Just because I am running Amazon Linux doesnt mean my container is and by including a Linux distro image I am ensuring that my container runs as, say, a Debian distro? That makes sense.

Comment: Right -- just because your host runs Amazon Linux doesn't mean your container has an Amazon Linux userland. All your container gets from the host is its kernel.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Awesome. That explains a lot to me and has probably saved me from a lot of headache. If you can compile your comments in to an answer I would be happy to mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Let me edit the title to make the actual question a little more clear, and I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Docker image runs in a set of filesystem namespaces which are unconnected from the host's except where you've chosen to bind-mount a volume. This means that **tools installed on the host are unavailable to the container**: Just because the host runs Amazon Linux doesn't mean that the userspace commands Amazon Linux provides (and the libraries those commands use to run) are available to the guests.

Without a Linux distro available inside the container, you wouldn't have a package management tool (`yum`, `apt-get`, etc) with which to install the tools you need to download a file, run software (that presumably needs to be linked to a libc, a copy of OpenSSL, or other shared components). There are also runtime parts of a working Linux system such as the resolver that are provided in userland by your distro and not shared from the host in a Docker install.

Using a base image ensures that you have tools available inside your container -- *and* it ensures that that container will work consistently on any Linux system with a compatible kernel and hardware architecture.

It's possible in theory to bind-mount many of the tools from the host (as by exposing all of `/usr` as a volume), but doing so would defeat many of the advantages Docker offers in portability.